# Staff text positioning

Tags: piano, notation

I have fermatas on the final notes on both staffs at the end of a piano piece.  I only want the fermatas held on the final refrain.  Do I need to include staff text to that effect above both staffs, or can I just include the text over the bass clef as it is kind of centered between the two staffs?

Answer (score 5):

According to the Schirmer Manual of Style ([bracketed] addition mine):

> Any text relating to tempo or its alteration goes above the staff (Allegro, *ritard., freely,* etc.).
> Bowing and mute indications are placed above the staff as well: con sord., pizz., harmon mute, sul pont., sul tasto, etc.
>
> Expressive indications as to how a performer plays a passage should always go below the staff [or between the staves of a grand staff], in italics: *espr., dolce, cantabile, with great passion, dryly,* etc.

A fermata is a tempo alteration, so text modifying its execution belongs above the staff.

Answer (score 4):

Use staff text above the upper staff. That's the standard placement for this type of instruction.